# 12.04 not detecting Apple Wireless Keyboard

Tags: bluetooth, apple, wireless-keyboards

I'm having some issues pairing an Apple Wireless Keyboard with my Asus laptop running 12.04 and Win7.  It does not have native Bluetooth, so I'm using a generic Rocketfish USB adapter.

I did get it to the PIN step, but mistyped and ended up cancelling.

Now, in the Setup New Devices, I notice that an entry flickers from time to time in the search box.  But no entry ever shows up.

What I've done so far:

- `sudo rfkill list` shows that `hci0: Bluetooth` is not hard or soft blocked
- `sudo hcitool dev` prints out **`hci0 00:02:76:2E:5D:4F`**
- I installed the `linux-firmware-nonfree` package
- Batteries are not an issue, keyboard works when booted in Win7

During the search process, when I turn on the keyboard, the keyboard light stays lit for ~4 seconds or so and then goes out.

Any other solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Try holding down the power button on the side of the keyboard and after a while it should enter pairing mode (blinking green light) during which it should become visible.

You may have difficulties trying to share the apple wireless keyboard between Windows and Ubuntu boots, as the keyboard remembers which computer+OS it is paired with. I have set it up to work with OSX and Ubuntu and the process tends to work better if you pair the keyboard with Ubuntu first. To get it to work with both Ubuntu and OSX I also had to follow the suggestion here to make sure they used the same link keys (to avoid having to repair it each time I switched boots),

[Leif Huhn (leif-dkstat) wrote on 2013-01-16](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bluez/+bug/1001825)

but I don't know if this applies to Windows as well. Hope this helps
in some way.